# The Ultimate Riddle

Tags: riddle

I am constructed unseen and askew,
slightly deceptive, the saying is true,
apart from my goal, my quest can’t be viewed,
but don’t bother asking, for therein is the clue.

Comment: Unless the title is part of it I'm a bit disappointed with the riddle.

Comment: I've been told by everyone who's solved it that the title is perfectly fitting.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Riddle

I am constructed unseen and askew,

> A riddle is constructed in secret, (or everyone would know the answer), and askew, because it can't be the complete truth or it would be too easy.

slightly deceptive, the saying is true,

> A riddle is slightly deceptive so there's some challenge

apart from my goal, my quest can’t be viewed,

> Weaker here. 
>  A riddle's goal is to get them to confusing them "amusingly". It's quest, which would seem to be the same thing? can't be viewed.

but don’t bother asking, for therein is the clue.

> The title is the clue.

Comment: not all riddles are sayings. You're on the right track, though!